# Multiple Forms one ajax function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have multiple forms generated from a database array(label:product_Name, label:sku_number, Input:qty_to_order & button:add). They all have same Class, and I'm having a problem on retrieving the data entered into each form (sku_number, qty_to_add, basically like a e-commerce kart). How can i process one @ the time using ajax function? thanks in advance

This is how i generate the forms

```
foreach($_SESSION['product_output'] as $row){
echo "<form class='thisclass'>";
echo "<input name='sku_number' type='hidden' Value='" . $row['sku_number'] . "'>";
echo "<input name='qty_to_order' type='text' Value=''>";
echo "<input name='add' type='button' Value='add' Onclick=''>";
echo "</form>";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jn0rf5p8/2/)**

You don't need to create a `form` tag if you want to submit this with ajax. However, you can put each product in a div tag to separate them. And here's how you can write the ajax for it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[name=add]').click(function(){
        $.post( "ajax/update_cart.php", {
            product_id: $(this).parent().find('input[name=sku_number]').val(),
            qty: $(this).parent().find('input[name=qty_to_order]').val()
        }, function( data ) {
            // AFTER SUCCESS YOU CAN UPDATE DOM
            // ex: $(this).parent().append('<p>Item added successfully<>');
        });
    });
});
```

[Here'](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)s more information about how to use the `$.post`

Comment: Thanks for ur answer, but when i click a button nothing happens, am i missing something?. I'm not even able to produce alert('') message.

Comment: @pipelian you won't be able to get the alert to work because the post is made on a page that is not found, and therefore the code in success scope won't execute. Change the post url according to your case and try the alert. NB: If you are on chrome press F12 and go to console to monitor the ajax calls, if you are on firefox, download firebug to monitor them

Comment: Amir could you provide me a small example of what should be on my second .php file and show me how to retrieve the info back to my first page?. I appreciate your help.  :)